# form_with client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side-validation

Im using the client side validation [gem](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations). And have ran the all the instructions as stated to get validation working, but validation doesnot work on my form.

My form:

```
<%= form_with(model: profile, local: true, method: :patch, multipart: true, validate: true) do |form| %>
```

I have put `validate: true` as stated on document.

Rather than put validation in my model:

```
  validates :name, :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }, if: :can_validate?

  def can_validate
    true
  end
```

The doc says you can force on the form which I have done instead:

And in my text field I have applied the validation:

```
<%= form.text_field :name, validate: { presence: true }, id: :profile_name, class:"input is-large" %>
```

But the validation does not work at all, no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a repo to reproduce your issue myself:

https://github.com/wmavis/so_rails_client_side_validations

It looks like client_side_validations works for me if I use form_for but does not work for me if I use form_with:

[image]

A search for "`client_side_validations form_with`" turned up this link:

https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/696

It seems like the easiest solution for you is to use form_for.  If you need to use form_with, it seems like the developer may be working on a solution or have one coded on another branch.

Let me know if it works or if you need more help.